# Django, Python, Mysql

Tags: python, mysql, django

This is the `settings.py` file for python. I set mysql up via macports (mysql5 & mysqldb) The problem is that I am unsure if I have `settings.py` configuration correct before I sync the db. Should the `PORT` be left blank? I believe it should. I know on my Mamp install I have it set to 3306. Thanks....

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql'
        'NAME':   'jenniwren'                     # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        'USER': '***'                     # Not used with sqlite3.
        'PASSWORD': '****'                  # Not used with sqlite3.
        'HOST': '/var/run/mysql5/mysqld.sock'                      # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
        'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
    }
}
```

update: this is what I am getting when I test the db in the shell..

demetrius-fords-macbook-pro-17:jenniwren demet8$ python manage.py dbshell
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 4, in 
    import settings # Assumed to be in the same directory.
  File "/Users/demet8/python_projects/jenniwren/settings.py", line 15
    'NAME':   'jenniwren'                     # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3306 is the default, so that should be fine.

Why do you have the host set to that? I haven't used MySQL on a Mac, but on Linux the host is 'localhost'.

The 'invalid syntax' is because you do't have a comma after the host string - wait, after any of the strings but the last one - and that is invalid syntax for  Python dictionary.

Comment: Alex I fixed the comma situation & left host blank. Unfortunately it's not picking up mysql @localhost. This is definitely due to it being installed via macports. I gotta find the path to mysql5 in opt/local/ & put in in my bash_login file. That should solve the remaining issue. Thank you.

Comment: I'm actually installing MacPorts and MySQL on my macbook today, too! If I notice anything about MySQL configuration for Django I'll make a note here.

Comment: If you are using MacPorts, you need to ensure that your shell search path includes /opt/local/bin; if you are also using a MacPorts Python, you need to include its bin directory, so something like this: export PATH="/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin:/opt/local/bin:$PATH"

Comment: Just FYI: I added this line to my bash_login file & voila it worked!  
Alex & Ned thanks for your help....

/opt/local/lib/mysql5/bin:

Comment: Thanks @demet8, I'll probably need that! I didn't get very far installing mysql on my Mac earlier today...